# prove that inner product set is bounded closed interval

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $X$ be real normed space, let $I$ be a non-empty index set, let
$\{ x_i: i \in I \}$ be a subset of $X$, let $\{ \alpha_i : i \in I \}$ be a subset of $\Bbb{R}^+$, and let $R > 0$. Consider the subset

$$S := \{ x^* \in X^*: \|x^*\| \le R \text{ and } | \langle x_i, x^* \rangle| \le \alpha_i \text{ for all } i \in I \}$$ of $X^*$. Take $x_0 \in X$. Show that the set $\{ \langle x_0, x^* \rangle : x^* \in S \}$ is a bounded closed interval on the real line.

I take a sequence from S such that it converges to y in the weak* topology and with the definition of S we get that S is closed in weak* topology. I think this idea is good for a start, but I couldn't finish the idea, so I need help.

Comment: Hi, I've formatted your question for you. Please check to see if I have made an error somewhere (e.g. I assumed one of the "R"s should have been $\Bbb{R}$). You should check out the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to format questions for yourself. Also, I note that $x^*$ did not appear after the $:$ in the set? This seems like an error, either in the question or in your transcription. Also, to get a good response on this site, you should discuss your thoughts about this problem too.

Comment: you have just missed to put ( * ) on x in the set S in the inner product |<xi, x*>| .....................

Comment: I've fixed it, and went out on a limb to say that the $x$ in $\|x\| \le R$ needed a * as well. Do you have any thoughts about this problem? It's important to share them, otherwise your question may be closed. Without bringing your question up to code, answerers can even get into trouble for answering it.

Comment: I take a sequence from S such that it converges to y in the weak* topology and with the definition of S we get that S is closed in weak* topology. I think this idea is good for a start, but I couldn't finish the idea, so I need help.